# Sorting by second word in perl

Tags: perl, sorting

Hey guys, 
I have this file called phonebook

```
Steve Blenheim:239-923-7366:238-934-7865:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:20300
Betty Boop:245-836-8357:245-876-7656:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:14500
Igor Chevsky:385-375-8395:385-333-8976:3567 Populus Place, Caldwell, NJ 23875:6/18/68:23400
Norma Corder:397-857-2735:397-857-7651:74 Pine Street, Dearborn, MI 23874:3/28/45:245700
```

And I am trying to sort the text in reverse alphabetical order from the second word (the last name) and have not been able to find out how to do it. I am reading from the file by doing this

```
  open (FILE, phonebook);
  @line = <FILE>;
  close(FILE);
```

any ideas? I can sort the first field in alphabetical order and reverse, but can't seem to get the second one to sort properly.
Thanks in advance

Comment: so you want to sort "Billy Bob Thorton" based on Bob? And "Dr. Martin Luther King Jr" based on "Martin"? Sorting is easy. The hard question is how to determine which is the surname...

Answer (score 10):

I share tadmc's concern that the second field, by whitespace isn't always going to be the surname, but answering the question as it pertains to the second field, you can get it using `split`, and you can sort it like this:

The simple but horribly slow version (easy to read, but it re-splits every field every single time it compares two lines, which is inefficient).

```
@lines = sort { # Compare second fields
    (split " ", $a)[1]
    cmp
    (split " ", $b)[1]
} @lines;
```

The [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) version (does the exact same thing as the previous one, only much faster):

```
@lines = map { # Get original line back
    $_->[0]
} sort { # Compare second fields
    $a->[1] cmp $b->[1]
} map { # Turn each line into [original line, second field]
    [ $_, (split " ", $_)[1] ]
} @lines;
```

Comment: +1 if you get rid of the horrible first example or label it "This is the wrong way to do it" and explain why.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using the shell, `sort -r -k2` will sort your file in reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Miguel Prz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546205/miguel-prz) solution I replaced the 'cmd' to '<=>'.
It is important for numbers. If the CMP is used, then sorting will work as a string (digits) - first character is most important, then second and so on. If you have the numbers: 607, 8 and 35 then CMP will sort it as: 8, 607, 35. To sort it as numbers we use the "<=>' method and the result will be: 607, 35, 8

```
use strict;

open my $FILE, '<', 'phonebook';
my @lines = <$FILE>;

my @sorted = sort { 
                my @a = split(/\s+/,$a); 
                my @b = split(/\s+/,$b); 
                $b[1] <=> $a[1] } @lines;

foreach my $item(@sorted) {
    print "$item\n";
}

close $FILE;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. The second field (by `split /\s+/`) for each of the lines in the sample input is "Blenheim", "Boop", "Chevsky", and "Corder". All of those will compare equal using `<=>`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to read the file line by line to do that. Something like this:

```
my %list;
open(FILE, phonebook);
while(<FILE>){
    my @vals = split(/:/, $_);
    (my $key = $vals[0]) =~ s/(\S+)\s+(.+)/$2 $1/; # split first field, reverse word order
    $list{$key} = $_; #save row keyed on $key
}

foreach my $key(sort {$b cmp $a} keys(%list)){
    print $list{$key};
}
```

Comment: Bad idea if there's ever a duplicate second field. Don't just assume it's a suitable key :)

Comment: @hobbs: But the key in my example is second-and-all-subsequent-words,space,first-word (of the first colon-delimited field). If that's duplicated in this example phonebook, all bets are off.

Comment: Fishy? Don't see how. It also makes sure that Bill Hobbs comes before Fred Hobbs.

Comment: right, which might or might not be what anyone is asking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's interesting to write in a Modern Perl way (the solution is the same), and this is the complete script:

```
use strict;

open my $FILE, '<', 'phonebook';
my @lines = <$FILE>;

my @sorted = sort { 
                my @a = split(/\s+/,$a); 
                my @b = split(/\s+/,$b); 
                $b[1] cmp $a[1] } @lines;

foreach my $item(@sorted) {
    print "$item\n";
}

close $FILE;
```

Comment: Kudos on the use of `strict` and 3 argument `open` with a lexical filehandle.  There are a couple of issues with your code.  First, you have a typo, you missed the closing brace on your sort block and didn't feed in the `@lines` array.  Second, sorting is an expensive operation, it runs at best O(n), at worst O(n^2) and on average O(n * log n).  This means a you'll be doing **a lot** of comparisons, and resplitting the keywords each time.  It's better to precompute your search terms.  You can use the Schwartzian Transform or use intermediate variables. It really pays to precompute.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised nobody has mentioned this, but if we are sorting a phonebook, we probably don't really want a pure ASCII sort.

Does `Bob DeCarlo`  really belong before `Ralph Dearborn`?  If you sort by using `cmp` Mr. DeCarlo winds up first in the results.

Even if you normalize for case, you've still got issues. There are a host of complications with sorting and filing things.  Different [organizations have rules](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/manuals/epmanual/ep495.htm) for [handling](http://www.texasals.org/42001lang.htm) these issues.

Since sort is an expensive operation, you'll want to make each comparison work as quickly as possible.  The way to do this is to use the simplest code possible for all your comparisons.  Since `cmp` won't give us the desired result by itself, we need to generate and cache a normalized sort term for each item in the phone book.

So, assuming you've already got your phone book data in an array:

```
sub extract_and_normalize {
     # Do stuff here to embody your alphabetization rules.

     return [ $normed, $line ];   
}

# Generate your sort terms
my @processed = map extract_and_normalize($_), @lines;

# Sort by the normalized values
my @sorted = sort {$a->[0] cmp $b->[0]}, @processed;

# Extract the lines from the sorted set.
@lines = map $_->[1], @sorted;
```

Or use the Schwartzian Transform, as `hobbs` suggests, to avoid making all the intermediate variables:

```
@lines = map $_->[1],
         sort { $a->[0] cmp $b->[0] }
         map extract_and_normalize($_), @lines;
```